# Nested foreach only loop once

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is wrong in my code. In the folowing code, say I have 3 items. `item name`, `item size` and `item quantity` will loop 3 times, thus shown as 3 rows on table. But `item price` and `item price * item quantity` only shown as one row? Why doesn't it show as 3 rows like the other?

```
$some_item = explode("#", $row->pesanan);
            foreach ($some_item as $one_item) {
                $item = explode(",", $one_item);
                $product_data = $this->produk_model->get_product_by_kode($item[0]);

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$item[0].'</td>'; <!--item name-->
                    echo '<td>'.$item[1].'</td>'; <!--item size-->
                foreach ($product_data->result() as $row_product) {
                    echo '<td>Rp '.number_format($row_product->harga, 0, ',', '.').',-</td>'; <!--item price-->
                }
                    echo '<td>'.$item[2].'</td>'; <!--item quantity-->
                foreach ($product_data->result() as $row_product) {   
                    echo '<td>Rp '.number_format($row_product->harga*$item[2], 0, ',', '.').',-</td>'; <!--item price * item quantity-->
                }
                    echo '</tr>';


            }
```

[**screenshot**](http://image.prntscr.com/image/dd3772763f4843d1bbc160f271486eaa.png)

Comment: what is the output. please share a screenshot

Comment: try using a for loop instead of while loop

Comment: Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Just to clarify: We are missing the data. One of the obvious answers to your question could be: "The data is incomplete, and therefore not rendered.".

Comment: You Need to show Value of '$row->pesanan' variable.